# How to select entire matrix except certain rows and columns?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a 5x4 matrix and I want to select all elements (to be set to 0) except those in rows 2 to 4 AND columns 2 to 3. Basically, all the elements along the "edges" of the matrix should be set to 0. Currently, my code is

```
mat[ -(2:4), -(2:3) ] <- 0
```

However, this (de)selects the elements in an OR fashion so instead, only the corners of the matrix are set to 0. How can I choose them in AND fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use functions `row` and `col` together with logical operations. The following works because R's matrices are in column-first order.

```
mat <- matrix(seq.int(5*4), nrow = 5)
mat[ !(row(mat) %in% 2:4) | !(col(mat) %in% 2:3) ] <- 0
mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    7   12    0
#[3,]    0    8   13    0
#[4,]    0    9   14    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `replace`

```
replace(mat * 0, as.matrix(expand.grid(2:4, 2:3)), mat[2:4, 2:3])
```

-output

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    7   12    0
#[3,]    0    8   13    0
#[4,]    0    9   14    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    0
```

#### data

```
mat <- matrix(seq.int(5*4), nrow = 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a two-step base R option

```
rs <- 2:4
cs <- 2:3
`<-`(mat[setdiff(seq(nrow(mat)), rs), ], 0)
`<-`(mat[, setdiff(seq(ncol(mat)), cs)], 0)
```

which gives

```
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    7   12    0
[3,]    0    8   13    0
[4,]    0    9   14    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0
```

**Data**

```
mat <- matrix(seq.int(5*4), nrow = 5)
```